# Are there ways to form a list from two arrays without using for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have two arrays, say `Y` and `X`, both of them are three dimensional array, say `2X3X4`. I want to construct a list like `[(X[0][0][0],Y[0][0][0]),(X[0][0][1],Y[0][0][1]),...,X[1][2][3],Y[1][2][3]]`. Are there any methods to do it in python without using for loop?

Comment: `x[0,0,0]` is easier to read

Comment: Why do you want a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first flatten your arrays, into a one-dimensionnal array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4) # shape is (2, 3, 4)
a = a.reshape(24)      # shape is (24,) so flattened

b = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)
b = b.reshape(24)
```

Then `zip` them to pair them

```
r = list(zip(a, b))
print(r) # [(10, 1), (20, 2), (30, 3), (40, 4), (50, 5), (60, 6), (100, 10), (110, 11), (120, 12), (130, 13), (140, 14), (150, 15)]
```